# Use the span value as color with CSS

Tags: css

I got the HTML:

```
<span class="poster_id">
xxxxxx
</span>
```

Is it possible to change the text color using the actual text value with only CSS? Like:

```
span.poster_id {
color: #xxxxxx;
}
```

Comment: No. that is something to do with JS or server side language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using jQuery:

```
var color = $(".poster_id").text();

$(".poster_id").css('color', color);
```

And if you want to do this dynamically, you can do this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(){
    var color = $(".poster_id").text();

    $(".poster_id").css('color', color);
});
```

and give `.poster_id` an attribute `contentEditable`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/mo7cjf4g/)

Comment: Query is _not_ CSS, it's a javascript library. One which can manipulate css, amongst other things.

Comment: @enhzflep, yes, but it is impossible to do this with css.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is get the innerHTML of an element with CSS, which is currently impossible. :(
However, you can do it with a little bit of JS(jQuery is **not** needed :D):

```html
<span class="poster_id" onkeyup="this.style.color=this.innerHTML" contenteditable>
xxxxxx
</span>
```

Comment: um... so you're saying that the color - say black, that's default - becomes the html of the span. that is exactly the _opposite_ of what jstuart wants to do.

Comment: @yak613 Haha, happens to everyone sometime :)

Comment: i thought it said that the color became the html... it looks like that because the left-hand side of the code should  be on the right: `this.innerHTML = this.style.color`. it's easier to read, i guess